# I'm trying to understand this code for my android app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to java and android development. Can some one help decode what this code is trying to say. I keep looking at it but I keep having the same issue at `EXTRA_SHOW_WEBONLY_BUTTON`. It is underlined by a red squiggly line. Do I need to create a button in the xml file to fix it or do I have to do something else? If so how do I do it? Thanks

```java
// When in doubt, show the "web only" button
    mShowWebControl = true;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        mShowWebControl = extras.getBoolean(RobotSelectionActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_WEBONLY_BUTTON,
                true);
    }
```

Comment: The red squiggly line means that there is a compile error. Mouse over it to see what the problem is.

Comment: You have to provide more information. In which class/activity is this code? Do you have a RobotSelectionActivity? I think this is missing and therefore the red squiggly line.

Comment: it says it is cannot be resolved or is not a field?

Comment: `EXTRA_SHOW_WEBONLY_BUTTON` is a field inside your  RobotSelectionActivity` class. Take a look here [RobotSelAct](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/UnTagged/cellbots/com/cellbots/RobotSelectionActivity.java.java-doc.htm)

Comment: You need to show a bit more rigor in trying to solve this problem before asking for someone else to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

`RobotSelectionActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_WEBONLY_BUTTON` is saying that in the `RobotSelectionActivity` class there is a static var called `EXTRA_SHOW_WEBONLY_BUTTON`.

So if the static variable is missing in the class or the class is not properly imported then you will get an error.